# Swift programming data type detection timing

Tags: ios, swift, type-conversion

In Swift programming language, is data type detection done at code writting time or code compilation time.

Comment: What does this question mean? Can you give some example of what exactly you mean here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since question is not very clear - I'm assuming that you want to know that if you write a statement as `let someVal = String.init()` - is `someVal` assigned as `String` when you write or when you compile.

As a general rule, even when you are writing code, the compiler is constantly working to ensure that you write correct things. This is why you get warnings and error while you're writing code. The same warnings and errors would also be replicated if you build the code in same state.

So, answer to your questions is - at both the times.